# I want to make the balls redraw with new random speed, color and position when they dissapear at the bootom of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I need help with my game. I want when the balls disappear at the bottom of the canvas to redraw on top with new position , speed and color not , but what i ended up with is just resetting its y coordinate to the default value and it just comes with the same color , size and speed.

I tried resetting the value of y to default when it reaches the bottom, but that doesn't satisfy me.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballsPerTick = 7;
var balls = [];
const viewLimit = canvas.height;

function cball() {
    return {
        x: random(10, 800),
        y: 0,
        ballRadius: random(10,40),
        color:"#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16),
        dy: random(1, 4)
    }
}

function drawBall(ball) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function random(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }

function updateBall() {
    balls.forEach((ball) => {
    ball.y += ball.dy;
   });
}

function draw() {
while (balls.length < ballsPerTick) { 
    balls.push(cball());
    balls.filter(ball => ball.y > viewLimit).forEach(ball => {ball.y = 10;});
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
updateBall();
for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    drawBall(balls[i]);
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

I want the balls to redraw on top of the canvas with new position , speed and color.

Comment: Please post code as a [mcve] . Cut and paste your code in the editor. Open the editor by clicking the bracket button `<>` which is the 7th button from the left on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code as follow.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballsPerTick = 7;
var balls = [];
const viewLimit = canvas.height;

function cball(ball) {
    if(ball) {
        ball.x = random(10, 800);
        ball.y = 0;
        ball.ballRadius = random(10,40);
        ball.color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
        ball.dy = random(1, 4);
    }
    else {
        return {
            x: random(10, 800),
            y: 0,
            ballRadius: random(10,40),
            color:"#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16),
            dy: random(1, 4)
        }
    }
}

function drawBall(indx, ball) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    console.log(indx, ball.x, ball.y, ball.ballRadius , ball.color, ball.dy);
}

function random(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }

function updateBall() {
    balls.forEach((ball) => {
        ball.y += ball.dy;
        if(ball.y > newViewLimit) {
            cball(ball);
        }
   });
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function draw() {
console.error('<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>');
updateBall();
for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    drawBall(i,balls[i]);
  }
}

function init() {
    while (balls.length < ballsPerTick) { 
        balls.push(cball());
    }
    ticker = setInterval(draw, 10);
}

init();


// clearInterval(ticker); // to stop interval function
```